# Groupby with handling empty bin in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have dataframe like below

bin=[0,5,10,15,20]

```
sex age
1    2
1   10 
1   11 
2   16
2   18
```

I tried

df.groupby([df.sex,pd.cut(df.age,bin)]).size()

I get result below

```
sex        age
1   (0,5]  1
1 (10,15]  2
2 (15,20]  2
```

But actually,I would like to get the result below.

```
sex      age
1   (0,5] 1
1  (5,10] 0
1 (10,15] 2
1 (15,20] 0
2   (0,5] 0
2  (5,10] 0
2 (10,15] 0
2 (15,20] 2
```

where is empty bin? And How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `dropna=False` in `stack`

```
df.groupby([df.sex,pd.cut(df.age,bin)]).size().unstack().stack(dropna=False).fillna(0)
Out[27]: 
sex  age     
1    (0, 5]      1.0
     (5, 10]     1.0
     (10, 15]    1.0
     (15, 20]    0.0
2    (0, 5]      0.0
     (5, 10]     0.0
     (10, 15]    0.0
     (15, 20]    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `unstack` and `stack`

```
In [4515]: df.groupby([df.sex, pd.cut(df.age, bin)]).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
Out[4515]:
sex  age
1    (0, 5]      1
     (5, 10]     1
     (10, 15]    1
     (15, 20]    0
2    (0, 5]      0
     (5, 10]     0
     (10, 15]    0
     (15, 20]    2
dtype: int64
```

---

Or, using `pivot_table`

```
In [4533]: df.pivot_table(index=df.sex, columns=pd.cut(df.age, bin), aggfunc=len,
                          fill_value=0)['age'].stack()
Out[4533]:
sex  age
1    (0, 5]      1
     (5, 10]     1
     (10, 15]    1
     (15, 20]    0
2    (0, 5]      0
     (5, 10]     0
     (10, 15]    0
     (15, 20]    2
dtype: int64
```

---

Or, using `reindex`

```
In [4546]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.sex.unique(), 
                                             pd.cut(df.age, bin).unique()])

In [4547]: df.groupby([df.sex, pd.cut(df.age, bin)]).size().reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
Out[4547]:
1  (0, 5]      1
   (5, 10]     1
   (10, 15]    1
   (15, 20]    0
2  (0, 5]      0
   (5, 10]     0
   (10, 15]    0
   (15, 20]    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you for answering!If I edit bin (0,5,10,15,20,25).It doesnt seem work well.I guess I must reset index...